# Preserve CR LF(New Lines) On Insert Into SQL Server

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyodbc

I am attempting to insert data into a sql server varchar(max) field and retain line breaks. These are addresses and the line breaks will be vital to parsing out address data. I am running the output in a window to see what the results are and the line breaks are maintained in the command line but not on insert into SQL Server

```
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(process):
    for file in files:
        dateadded = datetime.datetime.now()
        if file.endswith(('.dbf', '.DBF')):
            dbflocation = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, file)).lower()
            if dbflocation.__contains__("\\xxx.dbf"):
                table = DBF(dbflocation, lowernames=True, char_decode_errors='ignore')
                for record in table.records or table.deleted:
                    rec1 = record['key1']
                    rec2 = str(record['xxx1'])
                    rec3 = str(record['xxx2'])
                    rec4 = record['xxx3']
                    rec5 = str(record['xxx4'])
                    rec6 = record['address1'] #address to parse
                    # if table.delete == True:
                    #    rec42 = 1
                    cursor.execute(
                        "insert into tblepiqclaims(key1,xxx1,xxx2,xxx3,xxx4,address1) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                        rec1, rec2, rec3, rec4, rec5, rec6)
                    print rec6
            cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: If you are inspecting the table by opening it in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) then it may be deceiving you. SSMS does not display line breaks in a standard Grid View. You can use `CONVERT(VARBINARY, address1)` to see if the value contains `0D0A` (for VARCHAR) or `0D000A00` (for NVARCHAR) to verify that the CR_LF line breaks really are there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the escape character in the varchar field.

eg:

input = '1#2#3'

print input.split('#')